# Undergrad Research Topic in Number Theoy

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Im still having problems looking for possible topics in this field for our research, my prof recommended us to look into abc conjecture and collatz conjecture

Comment: maybe try the undergrad and mathematician stack exchange ( mathoverflow)  for ideas ?

Comment: see [Apostol's](http://plouffe.fr/simon/math/IntrodAnalyticNTApostol.pdf) book @RoddyMacPhee

Comment: ?? not sure what you mean

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee I think reuns thought you were the OP. I definitely don't think this question is appropriate for Mathoverflow, and it might not even be appropriate here. We don't know the OP or their background as well as their professor presumably does. Those who know their mathematical strengths and backgrounds would be able to suggest better projects.

Comment: The OP should also specify if this is a research topic in the sense of trying to make progress on the problem or a research topic in the sense of understanding the current status of a problem. The $abc$ conjecture and the Collatz conjecture are suitable for projects of the second type, and almost certainly not suitable for projects of the former type. If the latter is the case, I might also recommend Hardy and Wright's book on number theory, which has introductions to many topics in number theory which are accessible with minimal background.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to start is to look at a professor at your school or another school who studies number theory (and has worked on abc conjecture and collatz conjecture). Look at their CV, this will not only tell you the actual research they've done but will many times tell you what research topics they've advised on.

For example look at this CV I found: https://www.math.upenn.edu/~ted/LongerVitaPubs4-21-2017.pdf

If you look at PhD student sections you will be able to see many different topics that people have done. This can give you an idea as to a topic that is interesting and you can delve into.