# Is there any research problems in number theory an undergrad can give a try?

Tags: reference-request, big-list

I am an undergrad student and have a deep interest in number theory and now I am learning analytic number theory own for 3-4 months. I have also covered group theory. I want to work on research problems in Number theory. Unfortunately in my institute there is no Prof who works on Number theory.

Is there research problems that can be attacked by an undergraduate(may be part of an open problems) with a good background in Number theory?

I have checked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2423377/582443) answer, but in my country there are very few institutes working on Number theory and they are not accepting interns. I have to work on my own.

Comment: Basically, no. If it's a research problem, it probably requires techniques that are far beyond undergraduate level (algebraic geometry for instance). However, you could give a try to *historical* problems that are tractable by a good undergrad (say, Fermat's theorem for low exponents). You could also have a look at good introductory books in this area ([Ireland & Rosen](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387973296) comes to mind, maybe [Guy](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387208602))

Comment: Ok, if I manage to get help, can you name some problems then?